# Wordpress search result page first then post

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I tried to add a function for WP default search, I will like to make it result to shoe page items first, then post items, but it’s not quite working yet.
I’m not using any plugin for search.

Here’s my code(in function.php):

**First one**

```
<?php 
function filter_search($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', array('page', 'post'));

};
return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
?>
```

**Second one I tried:**

```
<?php
function filter_search($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', 
       array(
       'post_type'=>'page', 
       'orderby' => 'title',
       'order'   => 'DESC',
       )
       );
} else {
$query->set('post_type', 
       array(
       'post_type'=>'post', 
       'order'   => 'DESC',
       )
       );
};
return $query;
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using SQL CASE Expression

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'order_search_by_posttype', 10, 2 );
function order_search_by_posttype( $orderby, $wp_query ){
    if( ! $wp_query->is_admin && $wp_query->is_search ) :
        global $wpdb;
        $orderby =
            "
            CASE WHEN {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'page' THEN '1' 
                 WHEN {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'post' THEN '2' 
            ELSE {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type END ASC, 
            {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_title ASC";
    endif;
    return $orderby;
}
```

I found this solution here , https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177650/sort-search-results-by-post-type/177653#177653

Comment: Hi Sandeep Panchal | Thank you so much for your help, is possible to hide the home page for the search result? And make search result order by title or relevant? Thanks! –